# Ember JS to bind helpers inside specific div

Tags: ember.js, binding, append, appendto

Here I am facing the problem to bind my Ember.TextField into `<div id="bindhere"></div>` through IndexController without using template format. Because it appearing at the end of my code.

**Here is my Template**

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index" > < button  {{action  "select"   on="click"}}>OK </button> 
 {{outlet}}
</script>

**Here is my Controller**

App = Ember.Application.create();
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        select: function(param1, param2) {


               Ember.TextField.create({


                    classNames: ['btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'],

                    type:               'button',
                    attributeBindings:  ['value'],  value:  "New Button",
                    action:  '{{formeditchangefinder}}' ,
                    onEvent: 'click',

                    //attributeBindings:  ['on'],  on:  ['click']


                   eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
                       click: function(event, view) {
                           alert("working"+elementname);

                       }
                   })

                }).append();


        }
    }
});
```

Here I have attached the following thing in **JS-Bin** http://jsbin.com/dupagi/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correct -

check out this [Demo](http://jsbin.com/lawuxa/1/edit?js,output)

Basically you have to give an ID to the div you want to append to -

```
<div style="bindhere" id="bindhere"></div>
```

And then -

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        select: function(param1, param2) {

          var bindhere = $('#bindhere');


               Ember.TextField.create({


                    classNames: ['btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'],

                    type:               'button',
                    attributeBindings:  ['value'],  value:  "New Button",
                    action:  '{{formeditchangefinder}}' ,
                    onEvent: 'click',

                    //attributeBindings:  ['on'],  on:  ['click']


                   eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
                       click: function(event, view) {
                           alert("working"+elementname);

                       }
                   })

                }).appendTo(bindhere);


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes this one is working. But when I using this method inside my project I getting following **error**: **Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.**  , Could you have any Idea on this.